# How to add a consistent margin to each page when generating a PDF using jsPDF?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, download, jspdf

I'm currently working on a project that involves generating resume templates for PDF documents using the jsPDF library in JavaScript. I'm trying to add a consistent margin (specifically the bottom margin) to each page of the PDF, ensuring that the content does not touch the side of the page. However, the methods I've attempted so far haven't provided the desired results.

I've tried approaches like setting a footer function and adjusting the position, but unfortunately, I'm not achieving the expected consistent bottom margin on all pages. The issue seems to persist, and the content still touches the bottom of the pages.

I'm seeking guidance on how to correctly add a consistent bottom margin to each page of the generated PDF using jsPDF. Are there alternative methods or best practices to achieve this consistently?

I tried many below methods. check the code below this is the most appropriate code. now over here I am just not able to get the bottom margin in the pdf. So the main problem is the bottom margin on the pdf.

```
const handlePrint = () => {
    const pdf = new jsPDF({
      orientation: "portrait",
      unit: "mm",
      format: [297, 210], // A4 page size in mm
    });

    const content =
      types?.doctype === "resume" ? Resumeref.current : Coverref.current;

    const fontSize = 12;
    console.log("Page height:", pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight());

    // Calculate the zoom level to fit content within the page
    const pageWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 17; // Adjust for left and right margins
    const pageHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() + 10;
    console.log("Page height:", pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight());
    const contentWidth = content.clientWidth;
    const scale = pageWidth / contentWidth;
    const bottomMargin = 10; // Setting bottom margin to 10mm

    // Set the font size and scale the content
    pdf.setFontSize(fontSize);
    pdf.html(content, {
      x: 7,
      y: 7,
      html2canvas: { scale },
      callback: function (pdf) {
        pdf.save("document.pdf");
      },
    });
  };
```

[Image of what the issue is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNDQ4.png)

Answer (score 0):

To add bottom margin you can pass an array with numbers to margin key in the options of jsPDF.html method:

```
pdf.html(content, {
    margin: [0, 0, 10, 0],
    x: 7,
    y: 7,
    html2canvas: { scale },
    callback: function (pdf) {
        pdf.save('document.pdf');
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found alternate way. and it worked for me. using html2pdf.js

import html2pdf from "html2pdf.js";

```
 const handlePrint = () => {
const pdfOptions = {
  margin: 8,
  filename: "resume.pdf",
  image: { type: "jpeg", quality: 1 },
  html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
  jsPDF: { unit: "mm", format: "a4", orientation: "portrait" },
};

// Generate PDF from the HTML element
html2pdf().from(Resumeref.current).set(pdfOptions).save();
```

};